# Random number generator in Python when the mean is known

Tags: python, random

In Python, I am trying to get a list 10 random numbers between [0,100] that have a mean of 25. All the information I have is below.

```
Total = 250
Number_of_users = 10
Average_score = 25
```

In the past i have used the Gaussian function in random but without the standard deviation i am a bit stuck. Is there another way of doing it?

My output would be something like:

```
[20, 30, 18, 21, 27, 30, 15, 24, 31, 30]
```

Comment: Do you require them to be added up to a certain given number too?

Comment: Yes so if possible the total would be 250 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want `if possible the total would be 250 as well` then answer would be sampling from [Multinomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution). By definition, it will produce random values summed to 250 and with mean of 25. If one of the number will be above 100 (it would be quite rare), we will play acceptance/rejection game. With the help of NumPy

```
import numpy as np

Total = 250
Number_of_users = 10
Average_score = 25
Upper_boundary = 100

probs = np.full(10, 1.0/np.float64(Number_of_users), dtype=np.float64) # probabilities

N = 10000 # samples to test
k = 0
while k < N:
    q = np.random.multinomial(Total, probs)
    t = np.where(q > Upper_boundary) # check for out-of boundaries
    if np.any(t):
        print("Rejected, out of boundaries") # reject, do another sample
        continue
    # accepted
    # do something with q, print((sum(q), len(q), np.mean(q)))

    k += 1
```

Comment: Thanks this gives a really elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a thought:

```
import random

Number_of_users = 10
Average_score = 25

index = Number_of_users / 2
result = []

while index:
    index -= 1
    random_number = random.randint(0,51)
    result.append(random_number)
    result.append(50-random_number)

print (result)
print (sum(result))
```

You will get 5 pairs of random numbers; for each pair of random numbers, the first one is generated randomly between 0~50, while the second one is dependent on the first number.

One downside of my approach is, it does not handle odd number of random numbers.

Comment: For an odd number, insert a value of 25 into the list, keeping the mean unchanged.  After that is is possible to play with the list by picking a random increment/decrement and a pair of numbers, increasing one and decreasing the other (being careful about the limits on the values of the numbers).  That can be repeated many times to thoroughly mix up the final values.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the 2 constraints:

1. Numbers are random
2. Mean converges to 25

Since there's no constraint on distributions, one way to achieve this is by sampling from 2 different uniform distributions:

```
import random
out_list = []
for i in range(1,10):
    random_number = random.uniform(0,1)
    if random_number < 0.75:
        # Append uniform random number between 0 - 25 with probability .75
        out_list.append(random.randint(0,25))
    else:
        #Append uniform random number between 0-75 with probability 0.25
        out_list.append(random.randint(25,100))

print(out_list)
import statistics
print(statistics.mean(out_list))
```

Also, this question might find better home in stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The graph of the distribution of such numbers would be ... fugly, for the lack of the better word

Answer (score 0):

You can try a beta distribution with a mean value of 25, that is, choose a,b parameters such that a/(a+b)=0.25. You can get an idea of what variance you want in the graph below with varying a, b parameters.
[image]

```
from scipy.stats import beta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, figsize=(7,7))

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
a = [ 2.5,10, 25]
b = [ 7.5,30, 75]

for i in range(len(ax)):
    ax[i].plot(x,beta.pdf(x,a[i],b[i]))
    ax[i].text(0.75,0.75,"a={}, b={}".format(a[i],b[i]), transform=ax[i].transAxes)

plt.show()
result = list(map(int, 100*beta.rvs(10,30,size=9))) #to be more precise, need to check that these 9 values fall below 250
result.append(250-sum(result))
print("10 samples from a Beta(10,30) distribution:\n ",*result)



Out: 10 samples from a Beta(10,30) distribution:
  20 25 21 20 31 28 24 29 23 29
```

Comment: Well, numbers could be above 100 as well, but unlikely and quite easy to check. Real problem with this approach is that 9 numbers out of 10 will have something resembling Beta distribution, while 10th number will be VERY differently distributed.

Comment: Well, that's the limitation of setting the average equaling any number, it will be a degree of freedom less. No distribution will be accurate given such a condition.

Comment: `No distribution will be accurate given such a condition.` Huh?! Doesn't make sense. THere are distributions where such condition is satisfied by deifniton - Multinomial for integers, or Dirichlet for reals